# AngularJs: Render Directive from another Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives, both using `controller: 'SPFormController'`, both using `link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {}` constructor and both are in the view html code.

1. `<select-lists />`
2. `<form-list-fields list-id="" />`

renders first, ok, it brings me my lists, and the `link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {}` logs ok my selected value.

But how to pass selected-lists-selected-value to
 and get it rendered?

thanks!

Comment: here are several things which I wanted to point out 1. do close directive element correctly `<select-lists></select-lists>`(custom element are not self closing in natrure) 2. Do use `require` in parent directive & then put sharable content inside its controller, so that child directive can get that data from link controller parameter(4th parameter)

Comment: Very difficult to understand this question. Could you add more details and code/html?

Comment: @PankajParkar, 1. yes, it's just representation. 2. ngChange on `<select-lists></select-lists>` writes to controller. I've tried require on formListFields '^selectLists', gonna try it again. tks